# Apple Logic with Universal Audio Apollo-Record Wet and Dry Tracks and Headphone Monitor Wet?

Tags: audio-interfaces, logic-pro

First time poster here on sound design.  I am working on integrating my Universal Audio Apollo with my Apple Logic DAW and having some difficulty routing the following setups:

Guitar -> Apollo HiZ input

Record 1 wet track (plugins active)
Record 1 dry track (plugins inactive)
Headphones monitor the wet track

Vocal Mic -> Mic Line 1 XLR input

Record 1 wet track (plugins active)
Record 1 dry track (plugins inactive)
Headphones monitor the wet track

I’d appreciate any advice or templates from folks who have wrangled this before!

Thanks!
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the dry track record input to the same as the wet track.
Set the dry track output to "no output".